# Can I place and access a static library (.a) in the Documents or Library directory for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, static-libraries, nsdocumentdirectory, nslibrarydirectory

I would like to make my iOS app easy to update a library without updating the app to the App Store. So I think I may place and access a static library (.a) in the Documents or Library directory of the app.

Would this be possible? If so, how this can be done.

So far, I can put a static library (a.) in the Documents or Library directory of the app but cannot link this library from Xcode project.

Please give me any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This won't work. Static libraries must be linked into the final executable. And Apple doesn't allow for dynamic libraries.

You will have to submit an app update anytime you need to update any code.